# Tell Xcode to not use autolayout on project

Tags: xcode, cocoa, autolayout

Can I tell Xcode 4 that I do not use autolayout in a project?
At the moment, autolayout is on for every new xib created, which means I have to turn it off manually after creating one, and I don't want that.

Comment: please look into the project settings. which is by default on the right hand side.

Comment: I went there before asking. Had a look at project and target settings, and didn't find anything related. Care to give more details?

Comment: http://fredandrandall.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/saveasautolayout.png

Comment: Ill update you when i get back to my mac

Comment: @Navin Answers should be entered as an answer, not as a comment. And your solution works on a xib basis, I want to turn it off once for all the project.

Answer (score 0):

That's a problem with Auto Layout. You can't set it off in the entire code. You need to get it, as [G.H. made](http://www.goodbyehelicopter.com/2012/02/arggh-xcode-4-3-auto-layout-is-on-by-default-how-to-turn-off-auto-layout/).

Right now it's not perfect, but I suggest you to start taking a look at the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH1-DontLinkElementID_2). I also suggest you to watch the [WWDC 2012 sessions videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/), that cover this really great feature.